# how can i pass argument to celery task?

Tags: django, celery

this is my celery task

```
def task_a(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

and i call the task like following

arg1 is list and arg2,3,4 is integer

```
task_a.apply_async(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

and i got an error message

```
    File "/opt/envDjango/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 518, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
    TypeError: functools.partial object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int
```

how can i solve the problem??

i tried to make a dictionary and change argument position, they are all failed...

Comment: did you try `task_a.delay(arg1,arg2)`?

Comment: i change apply_async to delay, it work great!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`delay` will work. This method is convenient as it looks like calling a regular function: see doc [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay)

```
task_a.delay(*arg,**kwargs)
```

`delay` is clearly convenient, but if you want to set additional execution options you have to use `apply_async`.

```
task_a.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2])
```

> Note that the argument passed is a list.

Answer (score 12):

To pass arguments to task with `apply_async()` you need to wrap them in a list and then pass the list as first argument, I.e. `apply_async([arg1, arg2, arg3])`. See the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) for more details and examples.

Use `delay()` as an alternative. The benefit is that it preserves more or less function’s parameters interface, i.e. it is not needed to wrap the args in a list.